# altering blob container access permissions

Tags: permissions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to change the permissions of a container post its creation via the management portal?

The code below shows how to do it:

```
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);
        CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("sample");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        container.SetPermissions(
            new BlobContainerPermissions() { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
```

However, when I first executed it, I missed out on the SetPermissions call.

I searched the management portal for the same but couldn't find any option to change the container's permission.

Or is there a specific reason that one can't really find this option via the management portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Management Portal, select the container and click on the `Edit` button all the way on the bottom. That will give you the option to change the access permission.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice the command bars when I viewed all containers.